# How to read a text file that has integers ranging from 0-255 (representing grayscale pixels of images) and convert into a 2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a text file that has integers ranging from 0-255 (grayscale values of images of digits) all separated by tabs. I want to read the file using pandas/numpy and arrange it into a 2D array with 784 columns(representing the pixel values for each image) and the number of rows corresponding to the number of sample images I have. So each row would have 784 integers (28X28 pixel values of an image flattened). I want there to be a new row for each group of 784 integers. The file contains values for 2561 images so there are (2561*784)=2007824 integers all separated by tabs. So I want all these integers being split up and arranged into an array with 2561 rows and 784 columns.

Comment: Is there just one line with 200... numbers, or 2561 lines with 784 columns each.  In either case after loading the text into on integer array, it is easy to reshape it as needed, e.g. `arr.reshape(2561,28,28)`.  Have you tried `np.genfromtxt` with the `delimiter='\t'`?  Just reminder, check `shape` and `dtype` frequently.  Don't guess at that the code does; test it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read the file using pandas/numpy and arrange it into a 2D array with 1 column
>
> So each row would have 784 integers

If you want each row to have 784 integers, then you want 784 columns.

You can probably do something like this:

`images = pd.read_csv(<filename>, sep="\t", header=None)`

Comment: but now I get a dataframe of all the integers in one row. I converted the dataframe into an array by doing 'df = df.values' and I tried to reshape into having 2561 rows(number of images I have) and 784 columns(the pixel values for each image) but it gives me error 'cannot reshape size of array 1 into shape (2561,784)

Comment: It would be great if you could post the relevant parts of your code. It's hard to know what you're really doing otherwise.